# Trying to fix a run time error for S32K118 microcontroller based Cortex M0

Tags: c, embedded, nxp-microcontroller, automotive

i am trying to make an erase for flash memory from main.c,
 when i put a breakpoints in debugger (isystem ic5700 ) it erase succefully.
when i am trying to run the programm without any breakpoint , exception happens .
i read the status register of FTFC_FSTAT and i found that bit RDCOLERR indicates that a collision erro happens .

Comment: Without sight of the code an an indication of where you place the break point, how can we tell!?  Section 8.1 in [this app note](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN11983.pdf) discussed RDCOLERR and its causes.  The error is certainly in your code, but you have not provided that.  Flash write operations are asynchronous to the processor execution; I imagine you have started flash some operation, and failed to wait for it to complete before starting the next.  When you hit the break-point the operation has time to complete.  That's just a guess.

Comment: i am writing the FCCOB register with adresses and commands then i clear the CCIF  flag and waiting for it to be set to 1 again , i am running all that operation from functin i put it in the ram .

Comment: i don't have an access now , but this the bseudo code for the last line that i doubt .

clear CCIF flag  to lauunch the command.

While (CCIF flag ==1)
{
}

Comment: Well, there you are.  The CCIF flag is zero while the operation is in progress. So you need `while( CCIF == 0 ){ }`.

Comment: so sorry i meant != , i have check it already
while(bit_is_set(FTFC,CCIF) !=1)
{}

Comment: You need to place that information in your question not comments.  We cannot answer the temporary comments, only the question.   Explicitly testing the value of a Boolean function is unnecessary, error prone and generally bad form, and in this case confusing - better `while( !bit_is_set(FTFC,CCIF) ) { }`.  Even better: `while( bit_is_clear(FTFC,CCIF) ) { }`, or `loop_until_bit_is_set(FTFC,CCIF)` (these being other macros defined in `<avr/sfr_defs.h>`).

Comment: This phenomenon is common when you try to execute the code from the same bank that you are programming. It may then work by luck when single-stepping, even though the manufacturer makes no such guarantees. Same if you picked the wrong flash pre-scaler clock. And needless to say, all interrupts meddling with the flash to be programmed must be shut-off or told to work with RAM instead during programming.